# Bracketing is used as an insurance against (what) error?

Tags: bracketing

New to photography taking classes lol need help

Comment: Welcome to Photo.SE. I am sorry to have welcomed you here with a downvote on your first question, but I downvoted on the basis of "this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear". I understand that you are new to photography and are taking classes. But help us answer your question by explaining what you understand about exposure and bracketing, based on your class instruction. From there, we can help answer your questions, or clarify or correct any misunderstanding. But as it stands, this is not a good question for the Stack Exchange format.

Comment: @ scottbb - why interfere with a learning opportunity?

Comment: @AlanMarcus Because this is a Q&A site, not a teaching site. I know you treat it as something else, but the community (with guidance from the SE overlords) define what the site is.

Comment: Could I add a pedantic request for more punctuation, full sentences and no "lols" please?

Comment: @AlanMarcus on the contrary, I think this is _aiding_ a learning opportunity: _how_ to ask for help by "showing your work", demonstrating what one knows (or _thinks_ one knows), in order to help the helpers (answerers) write better responses; to give new members the opportunity to edit and improve questions (and therefore the opportunity to turnaround downvotes); and to encourage people to use the tools available (search, existing Q&A).

Answer (score 0):

We use the camera settings to make adjustments to the level of exposure that will occur when we press the shutter button. We are assisted by the camera's light metering system and its software. When using a modern camera, we might allows the camera to make all adjustments or we might choose to take matters into our own hands and make these adjustments manually. In either case, the resulting picture will likely be improved if the exposure settings were tweaked. As an insurance policy, it might be wise not to depend on just one possible setup. Bracket exposure to the rescue. We set the camera logic or we manually take a series of pictures in quick succession, each tweaked so we get several over a range from slightly under to slightly over exposed. The objective is obtain a faithful image.